# Laravel 4 retrieval of data

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've got a database, and in the database there are two tables called 'accounts' and 'players'. 
For the 'accounts' table I used the User.php model, and generated a new one for 'players' table. I've defined the relationships and everything.

**User.php**

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public static $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required|unique:accounts,name|min:4|AlphaNum',
        'email' => 'required|unique:accounts,email|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:4|AlphaNum',
        'password_confirm' => 'same:password'
        );

    public static $rules2 = array(
        'name'  => 'required|min:4|max:32',
        'password'  => 'required|min:4|max:255'
        );

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'accounts';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }


    /**
     * hasMany Relationship
     *
     */
    public function players() {
        return $this->hasMany('Player','account_id');
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if the account is an administrator.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isAdmin()
    {
        $player = Player::whereAccountId($this->id)->whereExists(function($query) {
            $query->select(\DB::raw(1))
                ->from('groups')
                ->where('groups.access', '>', 0)->where('groups.flags', '>', 0)
                ->orderBy('groups.access', 'DESC')->orderBy('groups.flags', 'DESC')
                ->whereRaw('groups.id = players.group_id');
        })->first();

        return (boolean) $player;
    }

}
```

**Player.php**

```
 <?php

class Player extends Eloquent {


    protected $table = 'players';

    protected $fillable = array('character_name', 'sex', 'vocation');
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Every player has a matching account_id column. I usually used `Auth::user()`, because all that I needed was my own account_id.

Now I have a third model, for a search form.

**Search.php**

```
    <?php

class Search extends Eloquent {


    protected $table = 'players';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

I think I've defined the relationship good on this one, if I did not, you could change it.

**What I need is when I search the data, and retrieve the specific player, to display other players that have his account_id.**

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. And why did you create a new model for a search form? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @KemalFadillah
I don't need a new model. Ok, where should I put it? I'm kind of new to all of this. When I search for a player, I have a specific view to display players information. I would also like to display other players that he has created. E.g.:

1->account id login1 loginpassword 
and each character has the matching account_id, his characters would be like: 1 Name other info.. 1->account_id, 2 Name other info.. 1->account_id..

Comment: Those two models (i.e. User and Player) should suffice. You called the right method to define the relationship, but you might've specified the wrong foreign key. If you got it right, however, retrieving the list of players of a certain user should be as simple as `$user->players`. Would you mind posting your tables' structure?

Comment: @KemalFadillah
accounts: http://2.imgland.net/CL_fi1.png
players: http://2.imgland.net/cBCPJZ.png

Comment: You've seem to got it right already. All you've got to do is access the `players` property of a `User` instance. It'll return a collection of `Player` that the user has created. Also you should pass in the custom foreign key in your `Player` model. That way the inverse relationship wouldn't be all wrong.

Comment: @KemalFadillah 
Could you clarify it a bit? How could I find the id of the specific user? By the custom foreign key? How do I create one? Do I need to create it, I think all I need is the account_id and the relationships.